# Запятая после вставки нужна?

Tags: вставка

Акунин говорит на Би-би-си: "Московия была построена на предельно жесткой, ордынской, вертикали власти, где только один человек в стране имеет значение – это государь. Все остальные – его холопы.
Кто бы они ни были – бояре, князья, последний крестьянин – все его холопы".

Наверное, надо так расставить знаки препинания: *Кто бы они ни были – бояре, князья, последний крестьянин, – все его холопы?*

Или так: *Кто бы они ни были – бояре, князья, последний крестьянин, все его холопы?*

А может, так: *Кто бы они ни были (бояре, князья, последний крестьянин), все его холопы?*

Или: *Кто бы они ни были (бояре, князья, последний крестьянин) - все его холопы?*

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что правильно так:

*Кто бы они ни были – бояре, князья, последний крестьянин, – все его холопы*.

Сравните: *Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие* (Сол.) — запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием *наряду с*.

**Неправильные варианты:**

*Кто бы они ни были – бояре, князья, последний крестьянин, все его холопы* (перед обобщающим словом *все* должно стоять тире).

*Кто бы они ни были (бояре, князья, последний крестьянин), все его холопы* (если находящаяся в середине предложения группа однородных членов, стоящих после обобщающего слова, имеет характер уточняющего замечания или может быть приравнена к обособленным приложениям, то она с обеих сторон выделяется тире).

Answer (score 2):

Если находящиеся в средине предложения группа однородных членов, стоящих после обобщающего слова, имеет характер уточнения или может быть приравнена к обособленным приложениям, то она может с обеих сторон выделяться тире: Ср.: ***Все эти люди - матросы разных наций, рыбаки, кочегары, веселые юнги, портовые воры, машинисты, рабочие, лодочники, грузчики, водолазы, контрабандисты  - все они были молоды, здоровы и пропитаны крепким запахам моря и рыбы.***

Справочник-практикум.  Д. Э. Розенталь. Стр.154.

> То же и вашем примере:  Кто бы они ни были  -  бояре, князья, последний крестьянин  -  все его холопы?

Comment: Этот пример к другому правилу. Это об обобщающем слове, которое повторяется: Все эти люди - все они были молоды. Или: Все эти люди: матросы, рыбаки - все они были молоды.

Comment: В четырех городах Италии - Риме, Неаполе, Турине и Милане - приняла старт финальная часть футбольного чемпионата Европы. 
Где повторяющееся слово в этом предложении? Из того же правила.

Comment: А этот пример из следующего правила, которое вы процитировали. Я смотрю Розенталь "Пунктуация" - самый подробный учебник.

Comment: Я тоже смотрю тот же учебник. Тат, будьте внимательны. Мой второй пример процитирован из правила, которое я привел выше. в своем ответе. Стр. 154.[§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)

Comment: У вас первый пример из п. 9, а второй из п. 10. Важно понять, какова базовая пунктуация без вставной конструкции. При повторяющемся обобщающем слове запятая маловероятна, так как нет перечислительной интонации. Не "Все эти люди, все они были молоды", а "Все эти люди - все они были молоды". А в анализируемом примере будет "Кто бы они ни были, все его холопы", поэтому запятая сохраняется.

Answer (score 2):

Кто бы они ни были – бояре, князья, последний крестьянин, все его холопы.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Старшая конструкция: Кто бы они ни были, все его холопы. Вставка относится к придаточному предложению, второе тире поглощается запятой.

Местоимение "все" здесь не является обобщающим словом, это структурный элемент для СПП (КТО БЫ НИ...ВСЕ)

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) Кто бы они ни были  – бояре, князья, последний крестьянин, – все (они)  его холопы.
Думаю, что в этом предложении  однородный ряд нужно оформить как вставку, отнесенную к придаточному, то есть обособить тире с двух сторон и поставить одну запятую. Это соответствует и интонации предложения.

Сравнить: Вот уже запахло деревней – дымом, дёгтем, баранками, послышались звуки говора, шагов и колёс. Это БСП,  второе тире поглощается запятой, интонация встроенная, не вставочная.

Слово «все» здесь относится к главному предложению, а однородный ряд – к придаточному, поэтому оно не может являться обобщающим словом.

2) В несколько минут он мог нарисовать всё что угодно: человеческую фигуру, животных, деревья, здания — всё выходило у него характерно и живо. Это БСП (В несколько минут он мог нарисовать всё что угодно — всё выходило у него характерно и живо).

Сравнить: Всё: и этот огонь, и эта вода, и тишина эта, и буря – всё входило в мою душу и соединялось в мою любовь. Это простое предложение с повтором обобщающего слова.

Comment: Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а **тире или** **ставится, или опускается**. Ср.: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие

Comment: Приведенный  вами пример - это оформление предложения с однородными членами после обобщающего слова. Можно сравнить с таким вариантом:  "К уютному запаху стариковских лекарств, как то: корвалола, валерьянки, капель Морозова ― примешались чужие резкие запахи каких-то мазей". В общем случае ставится просто тире, но если однородные члены имеют собственные знаки препинания, то ставится "запятая и тире". В вашем примере тире, скорее всего, тоже ставится как ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ЗНАК.

Comment: В заданном примере, наверное, тоже можно ПОСТАВИТЬ ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОЕ ТИРЕ, связанное с  тем, что  это  ряд, а не одно приложение, но только это не имеет никакого отношения к слову «все».

Comment: Вера, тире ставится на том основании, которое я привел в своем основном ответе. См.правило.

Comment: В вашем примере ЗАПЯТАЯ не нужна, но ставится. В заданном примере ТИРЕ обычно опускается, а там сохраняется. Думаю, что всё это влияние сложных или распространенных структур.

Comment: В этом примере согласно Розенталю запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием "наряду с", а не ставится как дополнительный знак.

Comment: Ну да, закрывает (ошибочное исправление). Тогда вопрос: когда тире ставится, а когда опускается? Это должно задаваться структурой предложения, а не быть авторским решением.

Comment: В книге такой пример: Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) — запятая как бы поглощает тире.

Comment: Но мы об уточнении или о приложении.

Comment: В "Трудных случаях пунктуации" Розенталь пишет, что тире в таких случаях ОБЫЧНО ОПУСКАЕТСЯ (как правило, в этих предложениях однородные члены не находятся между подлежащим и сказуемым - после перечисления идет независимое предложение).

Comment: Тире как дополнительный знак ставится в случае двусмысленности: На столе были разложены всевозможные предметы: книги, письменные принадлежности, географические карты, — которыми хозяин, по-видимому, давно не пользовался (тире нужно, чтобы показать, что придаточное предложение относится ко всем однородным членам, точнее, к обобщающему слову). Только я не уверена, что "все" не обобщающее слово. Можете доказать?

Comment: А вот пример из ПАС с повторяющимся обобщающим словом: В несколько минут он мог нарисовать всё что угодно: человеческую фигуру, животных, деревья, здания — всё выходило у него характерно и живо. И я не понимаю, почему тут нет запятой. Видимо, потому, что она не ставится перед обобщающим.

Comment: А если так: Кто бы они ВСЕ ни были — бояре, князья, последний крестьянин — ВСЕ его холопы? Получается, что второе ВСЕ все-таки обобщающее слово.

Answer (score 0):

Кто бы они ни были — бояре, князья, последний крестьянин, всё — его холопы.

Comment: @shampar, ՛՛все՛՛ не входит в ряд однородных членов, следовательно, тире после него не нужно.